# Split nested map

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I want to split the below mapping structure:

```
stages= {
        non_prod = {
            "qual"    = "token1"
            "dev"     = "token2"
        }         
        prod     = {
           "prod"     = "token3"
        }      
        testprod     = {
           "dev"     = "token4"
           "prod"     = "token5"
        }      
    }
```

Output should be in the below format:

```
stages= {
        "non_prod" = { "qual"    = "token1" }
        "non_prod" = { "dev"     = "token2" }         
        "prod"     = { "prod"    = "token3" }      
        "testprod" = { "dev"     = "token4" }
        "testprod" = { "prod"    = "token5" }
        }
```

So when the output is processed through a for loop, from **"non_prod" = { "qual"    = "token1" }** it will take te values as :
**environment = non_prod**

**stage       = qual**

**token       = token1**

Comment: The structure you want to produce is impossible because it shows a map with two values for each unique key. Can you say more about the underlying problem you are trying to solve, rather than the specific solution you're trying here, so that folks might potentially be able to suggest other strategies to solve the underlying problem?

Comment: @MartinAtkins,  The format is : ENVIRONMENT = { STAGE = TOKEN} , The unique key can be a combination of ENVIRONMENT-STAGE, so the format will look like : ENVIRONMENT-STAGE = { STAGE = TOKEN}

Comment: Make sure that you has a clear understanding of (key, value) mapping and JSON structure before attempt to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

Witht he below code you can accomplish to create an iterable that allows you to access the information required.

```
locals {

 stages = {
        non_prod = {
            "qual"    = "token1"
            "dev"     = "token2"
        }         
        prod     = {
           "prod"     = "token3"
        }      
        testprod     = {
           "dev"     = "token4"
           "prod"     = "token5"
        }      
    }

  solution = flatten([
    for env, data in local.stages : {
      for stage, token in data :  join(".", [env, stage]) => tomap({
        "env": env,
        "stg": stage,
        "tok": token
      })
    }
  ])
```

You can use the `merge` function and the `epsilon` operator to surround the output of the `flatten` function to obtain an iterable map in the way you can use it later as required.

```
> merge(local.solution...)
{
  "non_prod.dev" = {
    "env" = "non_prod"
    "stg" = "dev"
    "tok" = "token2"
  }
  "non_prod.qual" = {
    "env" = "non_prod"
    "stg" = "qual"
    "tok" = "token1"
  }
  "prod.prod" = {
    "env" = "prod"
    "stg" = "prod"
    "tok" = "token3"
  }
  "testprod.dev" = {
    "env" = "testprod"
    "stg" = "dev"
    "tok" = "token4"
  }
  "testprod.prod" = {
    "env" = "testprod"
    "stg" = "prod"
    "tok" = "token5"
  }
}
```

That is an iterable map that you can access the data through by it keys (`env`, `stg`, `tok`).